# Why is port 1028 deprecated?

Tags: port

IANA [lists](https://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.txt) port 1028 with the simple description "Deprecated". Hundreds of other ports are listed as "Reserved", and hundreds more as "Unassigned", but only one port has the description "Deprecated".

I'm trying to understand the difference between these three states, and would like to know what history led to port 1028 being in this unique state [as of February 2004](https://www.speedguide.net/port.php?port=1028).

There appear to have been some [security concerns](https://www.grc.com/port_1028.htm) with the ports 1025-1029, but the other four ports haven't been deprecated and are currently assigned other roles.

Comment: It was still unassigned [as of October 2003](https://web.archive.org/web/20031001220553/http://www.iana.org:80/assignments/port-numbers).